# Facebook comment and other commenting system for SEO

Tags: seo, comments

Lately i see some of big websites begin using Facebook commenting system in their wordpress websites. There are also websites that stick to commenting system like Disqus, IntenseDebate and Livefyre.

My question is between Facebook Comment and Comment System (Disqus, IntenseDebate and Livefyre) which one is better in terms of SEO?

Answer (score 5):

**The default integration** method for all of them -- Facebook, Disqus, IntenseDebate and Livefyre -- is to use Javascript to include the comments in the browser. Thus Google and other spiders cannot see the the user generated comments, as these don't exist in the parent page HTML.

So in terms of on-page SEO you don't benefit at all from user generated content on these hosted commenting systems. (User engagement and ease of use is of course another story.)

Disqus has a documented workaround for including their comments directly into the parent page. It's not pretty, but it [should work well enough if you have PHP and (My)SQL](http://docs.disqus.com/help/58/).

See also "[Add comments to 'static' pages without Javascript so they're Google-able?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/28611/1857)"

Comment: Matt Cutts from Google [said in a Tweet last Nov 2011](https://twitter.com/mattcutts/status/131425949597179904) that Google "Now has the ability to execute AJAX/JS to index some dynamic comments". And others have reported that [Google Indexes JavaScript based Facebook Comments](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-indexes-facebook-comments/20295/)

Answer (score 2):

What I'm seeing is a change from being SEO to Social.

If you have your own commenting system, then search engine will see the text user post but not their friend on facebook.

If you use facebook commenting system, search engine might not see the text of user post but all their friends will.

The other thing to think of is control. Do you want to own the text user post or do you want facebook to own it.

Answer (score 2):

There is some evidence out there that Google is starting to use a headless browser that is capable of seeing all ajax loaded content, versus just looking at your raw html.  I'd suggest you look around on SeoMoz as I'm sure this topic has been addressed many fold over there.

Answer (score 0):

the comment in systems like Disqus, Intensedebate and Livefyre are synced with the database from your wordpress install. I'm not sure about facebook, in the past it was just some ajax/javascript code which shows the comment made actually in facebook.

I think a hosted comment system is great because of the social features and not because of SEO. None of them will approve your SEO, it might be the opposite because these systems need to sync a new comment with your website first and that might be later than a comment picked up google on a 3rd party site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with these SaaS comment systems, but in terms of SEO the only thing that should have any effect is whether the comments are visible to Google or not, i.e. whether Google treats the comments as more page content or the comments are basically treated as SEO-inert.

I believe Facebook now uses `iframe`s to embed their comment system. This most-likely means that, though Google might see and crawl the comments, they won't be considered part of the page. So whereas internal commenting systems add additional indexed content to the page, Facebook comments are simply treated as a separate page.

Disqus supposedly renders a plain-text, non-framed version of the comments on the page in a hidden `div`. And there's [some evidence](http://www.seanpercival.com/blog/2011/05/13/how-to-make-facebook-comments-seo-friendly/) that this works for most sites. It's technically cloaking, but Google probably won't penalize you for it since the user sees the same thing (just through the `iframe` rather than the hidden `div`).

Other people have also used OpenGraph to insert Facebook comments directly into the page in a manner similar to Disqus. It's not an ideal system, but since most of these comment systems are embedded via `iframe`s, it's the only way to make them SEO-friendly.

There are other benefits and drawbacks to various systems, but none of them directly relate to SEO.

Answer (score -2):

This widget requires that you have a Facebook account and that you create a Facebook Application to associate the comments with so that you can moderate the comments. The process for creating an application is only a few clicks and available for anyone and is described in the section below.

Comment: You didn't address the question asked at all.