# Add comments to 'static' pages without Javascript so they can be index by search engines?

Tags: seo, comments, user-engagement

Are there any often mentioned products or services for adding end user comments to pages that aren't served up by a CMS or blog engine? Assuming the host can execute PHP, Python, ASP.NET classic, or other very common programming languages.

The solution must:

- Allow end users to **leave a comment on a web page**, with an easy login process for the user.
- Store and emit the comments in such a way that they can **be crawled by search engines, and are indexed as part of the parent page**. (The only way I know of would be to in-line the comments as plain HTML in the parent page, using PHP / SSI / etc. AFAIK this rules out all Javascript-based solutions such as [Facebook's Comments Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)?)
- Have very robust anti-spam capabilities, preferably with some sort of heuristics and  crowd-sourced blacklists (like Akismet).
- Have an administration backend with spam management and batch approve capabilities.

This is related to but still different from ["Adding comments to static pages?"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/1283/1857). There is also the more recent ["Facebook comment and other commenting system for SEO"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26805/facebook-comment-and-other-commenting-system-for-seo).

It would be ideal if the solution could easily be integrated in the HTML using just a Javascript, an IFRAME, or something similar. But a light-weight server module written in PHP or another common web development language is also good.

Answer (score 3):

**Disqus** does have the option to cache comments locally, and emit them into the parent page. But it's neither easy nor elegant. Their [documented solution is to create a database table, and set up a cron job to query their API, using their API client code](http://docs.disqus.com/help/58/).

**For the Rails crowd: Juvia seems very interesting.** It's a [self-hosted generic commenting system which works much like Disqus or IntenseDebate](https://github.com/phusion/juvia). It also uses Javascript as its default method of embedding comments, and thus doesn't meet my SEO requirements. But changing over to conventional HTML views shouldn't be too hard for a Rails programmer.

**Livefyre** claims to have SEO baked in too. I can't see exactly how they do it, and their API is only enabled on the commercial plan which doesn't have public pricing.

**Another potential way** would be embedding Wordpress comments into PHP pages. The Wordpress `wp_list_comments` [seems to be for just that](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_comments). However, Wordpress is well known for requiring server-side resources and some performance tweaking. If I am to use Wordpress' comments, then it seems I might just as well migrate the entire site to Wordpress. That's exactly what I wanted to avoid.

**So far I really haven't found anything that fits.** There is an accepted answer waiting for he who finds something better...

Answer (score 2):

[Disqus](http://disqus.com/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Doesn't Disqus use Javascript?

Comment: Yeah, but apparently Google indexes them. I'm guessing they went out of their way to make sure they could due to its popularity.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess if they just load something via Javascript without any specific interactions then it should be fine for Google.

Comment: {{citation needed}}

Answer (score 0):

Well while the title says without Javascript I think it's clear some kind of client side scripting would be needed. Disqus is good here is another system.

IntenseDebate
http://www.intensedebate.com/